# Extracting map values as ArrayList from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, collections

I created a simple class `MapExtension` to accomodate passing of 4 values to a listview adapter and used `LinkedHashmap` to add the ArrayList of MapExtension.

```
public class MapExtension {
private String studname;
private String studnumber;
private String schedule;


public MapExtension(String studname, String studnumber, String schedule) {
    this.studname = studname;
    this.studnumber= studnumber;
    this.schedule= schedule;
}

public String getStudname () {
    return studname;
}

public String getStudnumber() {
    return studnumber;
}

public String getSchedule() {
    return schedule;
}
```

}

Whenever I try to extract the `ArrayList<MapExtension>` from LinkedHashMap returning `Collections`, I get these errors from different trials(in comments):

```
ListViewAdapter(Context context, LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MapExtension>> mValues) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_layout, mValues.keySet().toArray());
    this.context = context;

    //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values 
    //cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    ArrayList mValues = (ArrayList) mValues.values();

    // says incompatible as it will become ArrayList<ArrayList<MapExtension>>
    ArrayList<MapExtension> mValues = new ArrayList<>(mValues.values());      
}
```

How can I successfully retrieve it and place in its compatible type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every `value` of `mValues` is an `ArrayList<MapExtensions>`, and `values` returns an `Collection<V>`, so you should be able to do..

```
Collection<ArrayList<MapExtensions>> localVar = mValues.values();
```

If you want to flatten your nested arrays, you can look at the streams flatMap() method.  [Here is one person's blog on that](http://www.baeldung.com/java-flatten-nested-collections).  BTW, Kotlin collections have a flatMap() extension method that works on collections.

Comment: This leads me to `Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+`. I can't make it work yet as Android Studio does not allow me to use version 1.8 but only until 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correcly, given `LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MapExtension>> mValues`, you want `ArrayList<MapExtension>` flattening the values of the input map. With Java 8, you could easily do it like this:

`ArrayList<MapExtension> extensions = mValues
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);`

A small tip: you should program against interfaces so instead of using `ArrayList` in your types, think about using `List` so that you are not tied to one particular concrete implementation everywhere.

Comment: Given that the SO would likely be better off using `List<MapExtension>`, is it better to `flapMap(List::stream)` then `collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: Yes, it does get simpler in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm having `Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+` by using that code and AS only allows me to use 1.7.